# Zeppelin Invalid ticket error

Tags: session, centos7, apache-zeppelin, ambari, http-status-code-503

I am using zeppelin on hdp-2.5.3.

The following error occurs continuously, when running zeppelin..

The error:

```
ERROR [2017-04-21 13:28:18,852] ({qtp209813603-18} NotebookServer.java[onMessage]:211) - Can't handle message
java.lang.Exception: Invalid ticket 8e410f58-133d-48f2-86df-43d647221463 != b31d3ddb-499d-4cd7-a11f-6e8c6fdbdfa8
at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer.onMessage(NotebookServer.java:117)
at org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookSocket.onWebSocketText(NotebookSocket.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:65)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:632)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

503 error occurs when restarting. 
After deleting the notebook , and it works normally.. 
Could this just be a notebook issue?

Comment: Could clarify the version of Zeppelin you're using?

Comment: @Khalid zeppelin version is '0.6.0'

Comment: hdp version is '2.5.3.0-37'

Comment: It looks related to [ZEPPELIN-1298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1298), did you try upgrading to versions '0.6.1' or '0.7.x'?